# How to accept POST data in Node.js

Tags: python, http, node.js

I am using NodeJS to send notifications to my clients using `NowJS` but the data that I need to send in the notifications has to come from my database.

Since I am using Django backend, I can make HTTP requests to my Node.js server and send the required data. But I need to be able to accept this data using Node.js. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you create an HTTP client in node.js that call your backend and return data back to nowjs ?

Comment: No the problem is that I am sending notifications, so whenever a notification is generated only then I need to send them. If a client in node.js calls my backend, then how would it know when a new notification has come up?

Comment: Your may use your node.js client to poll your backend for new notifications, then publish them through nowjs.

ex: setInterval(pollFunctionName(),(24*60*60*1000));

Comment: I wanted to avoid polling, when I can send HTTP requests from my backend to the Node.js server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of using Connect/Express, so here's a trivial example you could use:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(app);
app.use(express.bodyParser()); //If you want nice JSON parsing

app.post('/sendNotification', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params) //Look at the POST params
  console.log(req.body) //Look at the POST body

  everyone.now.receiveMessage(req.body.dataYouCareAbout); 

  res.send('Notification Sent!');
});
```

You could then use that "sendNotification" endpoint to accept POST data and send it (or some piece of it, or anything really) down to NowJS.

Comment: Quick comment:  This is closer to pseudocode than real code (I don't use NowJS locally and their APIs change quite often) but hopefully it gives you the right idea.

Comment: Yes I have understood the gist of it, but you said that you don't use NowJS because their APIs change quite often, so is that likely to cause me a problem. Because I will be relying on NowJS to send real time notifications

Comment: I said I don't use it, not that I've never used it before.  I used NowJS a long while ago.  The "everyone.now.receiveMessage" line is directly from their documentation.  How is my not using NowJS relevant to your implementation anyway? :)

Comment: I was just taking your feedback, because we will be using in production phase, and i you felt you had some problems using it, maybe that can provide me with some insight

Comment: I didn't have any problems using it, the project just went in a different direction.  It was pretty buggy when I used it but that was a while ago, around v0.3.  I've heard it's fairly solid now!

Answer (score 3):

> How can I do this?

```
require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
  doStuff();
}).listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable). Here's a short example from their docs:

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    return;
  }
```